# Phonegap backbutton event listener runs only once after installation

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a phonegap app where I override the Back button behavior on Android using the following code:

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

      document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
         backButtonPressed();
      }, true);
```

In the `backButtonPressed()` function I run a simple alert box to notify me that the function has been called and return false;

I am testing it on Android 2.3 using Cordova 3.1.

My problem:

The code run only once after I install the app and therefore overrides the exit of the application using the back button. The second time and on the back button closes the application and the function is not running the second time. Even after closing the app and running it again the function is not running, only the first time it is installed.

I've added the `addEventListener` of the backbutton after the `deviceready` event listener as needed.

Thanks.

Comment: backButtonPressed code?